# DrawToBitmap missing the bottom right corner of the panel

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

I am using DrawtoBitmap to save drawings from a panel to a specific location, however when I open the file, the bottom right part of the image, where parts of the drawing should be is blank.
This blank rectangle seems to vary in size drawing to drawing.
Here is my Code:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);   
Rectangle rect = panel1.RectangleToScreen(panel1.ClientRectangle);
g.CopyFromScreen(rect.Location, Point.Empty, panel1.ClientSize);
g.Dispose();

panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, rect);
```

I then use SaveFileDialog to store the bitmap.
The problem could be that the panel I draw on is docked in a parent toolStripContainer.ContentPanel, I'm not sure.

Any thoughts or solutions on this matter are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try different margin and padding?

Comment: Showing you snapshot will be also helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Rectangle rect = panel1.RectangleToScreen(panel1.ClientRectangle);
...
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, rect);
```

You are just passing the wrong rectangle.  It is in screen coordinates, it needs to be in client coordinates.  You got into this trouble by using CopyFromScreen(), it indeed does require screen coordinates.  But doesn't do anything useful, just get rid of it.  Fix:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, panel1.Size);
panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, rect);
```